# ava: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Why is it such a big deal to run a simple springboot project in intellij?

The same issue has been discussed earlier as well, but those solutions didn't work for me. So I have opened a new question.

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-201.7846.76, built on June 1, 2020

I have used spring initializr to create a simple maven based springboot project
[image]

I have JDK 11 installed on my system. The same project works fine in Eclipse. What is the deal with intellij and why is it so hard to sometimes make it work for simple things.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ps</groupId>
    <artifactId>conferenceo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>conferenceo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Error Log

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'conferenceo'
Information:javac 11.0.3 was used to compile java sources
Information:7/6/2020 10:08 AM - Build completed with 4 errors and 0 warnings in 2 s 593 ms
C:\PersonalWorkspace\Pluralsight\conferenceo\src\main\java\com\ps\conferenceo\ConferenceoApplication.java
Error:(3, 32) java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
Error:(4, 46) java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
Error:(6, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
Error:(10, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class com.ps.conferenceo.ConferenceoApplication
```

External libraries downloaded

[image]

Main Java class

```
package com.ps.conferenceo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConferenceoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConferenceoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please give more information, error logs or error screen in IntelliJ

Comment: Have you actually imported the project as a maven project and refreshed the dependencies?

Comment: @silentsudo Question updated with error log.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes. Imported the project as Maven and refreshed dependencies a thousand times.attached screenshot of external libraries downloaded

Comment: Can you please post main java class with imports?

Comment: @silentsudo Done.

Comment: I just gave up and started using STS. The same project imported in STS works fine without the need to do anything else. It just simply works. Intellij is weird. A lot of things are good about it but things like this issue drives me nuts.